# Splitting string and sorting in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sorting, split

I have a table in postgresql with a text column that has values like this:

```
column
-----------
CA;TB;BA;CB
XA;VA
GA;BA;LA
```

I want to sort the elements that are in each value, so that the query results like this:

```
column
-----------
BA;CA;CB;TB
VA;XA
BA;GA;LA
```

I have tried with *string_to_array*, *regexp_split_to_array*, *array_agg*, but I don't seem to get close to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this would be easy to understand:

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        unnest(ARRAY[
            'CA;TB;BA;CB', 
            'XA;VA', 
            'GA;BA;LA']) AS txt
)
SELECT
    string_agg(val, ';')
FROM (
    SELECT
        txt,
        regexp_split_to_table(txt, ';') AS val
    FROM
        tab
    ORDER BY 
        val
) AS sub
GROUP BY
    txt;
```

First I split values to rows (`regexp_split_to_table`) and sort. Then `group by` original values and join again with `string_agg`.

Output:

```
BA;CA;CB;TB
BA;GA;LA
VA;XA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably overcomplicating it:

```
t=# with a(c)as (values('CA;TB;BA;CB')
,('XA;VA')
,('GA;BA;LA'))
, w as (select string_agg(v,';') over (partition by c order by v), row_number() over (partition by c),count(1) over(partition by c) from a,unnest(string_to_array(a.c,';')) v)
select * from w where row_number = count;
 string_agg  | row_number | count
-------------+------------+-------
 BA;CA;CB;TB |          4 |     4
 BA;GA;LA    |          3 |     3
 VA;XA       |          2 |     2
(3 rows)
```

and here with a little ugly hack:

```
with a(c)as (values
('CA;TB;BA;CB')
,('XA;VA')
,('GA;BA;LA'))
select translate(array_agg(v order by v)::text,',{}',';') from a, unnest(string_to_array(a.c,';')) v group by c;
  translate
-------------
 BA;CA;CB;TB
 BA;GA;LA
 VA;XA
(3 rows)
```